# How to get only the max string length column row from a table using linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table like the following image with two column "cas" and "pref"  and you can see there are common values in "cas" column so i want to group by "cas" and fetch only the rows those have max string length in the "pref" column using the Linq in c#.

Input Table:

[image]

Required Output:

[image]

I am using following query to get the upper required output in sql but how to do it by LINQ?

```
select cas, (select top 1 pref from pdf_tab b where b.cas = a.cas order by LEN(pref) desc )
       from pdf_tab a group by cas
```

Comment: Sorry I want LINQ.

Comment: it has flags C# and LINQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return longest element from each group:

```
      var results = from p in tablename
      group p by p.cas into g
      select g.OrderByDescending(e=>e.pref.Length).First()
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var results = yourTable.GroupBy(x => x.cas).Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(og => og.pref.Length).First());
```

Answer (score 1):

I presumne that the data structure is like this:

```
class Data
{
   public int cas {get;set;
   public string pref {get;set;}
}  

and some record:

List<Data> records;
```

because you said C# and LINQ, it has to be that way:).

From there it is simple:

```
List<Data> newRecords =
records
.GrouBy(data => data.cas)
.Select(gData => gData
                 .OrderBy(x => x?.pref?.Length ?? 0)
                 .LastOrDefault())
.Where(data => data != null)
.ToList()
 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = from p in tablename
          group p by p.cas into g
          order by g.Key
          select new { cas = g.Key, maximum = 
g.First(r => r.pref.Length == g.Max(y => y.pref.Length)) };
```

Comment: Its not returning max length value...its returning the first values only like "water" from cas "1000" but i need "ldkfldkflkdlfkdlfkldk" from cas 1000

Comment: can you try putting g.Max(x => x.pref.Length)

Comment: yeas i have added the same

Answer (score 0):

You can order all your data from the table descending by the length of the **Pref** property, group them by **Cas** value and then get only the first element from each group.

```
var result = from p in table
             orderby p.Pref.Length descending
             group p by p.Cas into g
             select g.First();
```